# How to re-run Diesel migrations?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I'm using Diesel with PostgreSQL. I added my migrations, and they worked fine, outputting everything in the `schema.rs` file. Until I noticed that I was missing the `created_at` fields on some of my migrations. I edited the SQL and ran `diesel migration run`. Nothing happened, no errors, no success. Is there a way to fix this and re-run my migrations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The command

```
diesel migration run
```

Only applies migrations. If you would like to revert a migration you have to run:

```
diesel migration revert
```

Using these commands together you can "redo" an applied migration like this:

```
diesel migration revert
diesel migration run
```

This pattern is common enough that `diesel` provides this shortcut command that does the same thing as the above 2 commands:

```
diesel migration redo
```

Note: all of these commands only run, revert, or redo a single migration at a time. If you want to run, revert, or redo multiple migrations or all migrations you're going to have to manually run the commands multiple times, that is until a new version of `diesel` is released and [this feature](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/pull/2401) becomes available, when you'll be able to redo all migrations by simply running:

```
diesel migration redo --all
```

Note: all of the commands will only work correctly if you've written a `down.sql` for every migration you intend to revert or redo.

Comment: I run `diesel migration redo` and it working but it still isn't updating `schema.rs`

Comment: GitHub repo here: https://github.com/henryboisdequin/vsreview

Comment: I've updated my answer. Run `diesel migration redo all`.

Comment: I get an error when I run `diesel migration redo all`. `error: Found argument 'all' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context`

Comment: Oh, [this PR was merged 3 months ago](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/pull/2401) but unfortunately diesel hasn't been released since then so the feature isn't available yet. You're going to have to manually run `diesel migration revert` for however many migrations you need to revert and then run `diesel migration run` to redo them all.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but Diesel needs to release that feature though...

Answer (score 1):

The correct procedure is to create a new migration (`diesel migration generate`), then add ALTER statement to up.sql to alter your existing schema.  Then you can simply `diesel migration run`.  Once that is done, you can use `diesel print-schema` to get the updated code to write into schema.rs.